# no display after installing graphic card

Tags: graphics-card

I have a PC with "gigabyte 1050 g1 series with ddr4 4gb ram and core i3 6300(maybe) and integrated Intel 53"0 GPU. Recently I bought a "zotac gtx 1050 to 4gb 128 bit". But when I plug it in there is no display on monitor. Not even bios logo. But the fan on GPU running. Some sites said cable is required. But I saw some youtube installing this model but they did not plug any cable. And it only has dvi, dmi and dp port and my monitor only had VGA.

Comment: *And it only has dvi, dmi and dp port and my monitor only had VGA.* So how did you connect the card to the monitor?

Comment: I didn't. Youtubers also didn't use any cable.

Comment: Does all GPU need external display cord?

Comment: The data isn't going to get from the Zotec card to your monitor without the help of a cable.

Comment: Can a dvi to VGA adapter work?

Comment: Yes, I believe it should work.

Comment: I would love to see one of those videos with a wireless monitor.

Comment: Of course You need to connect videocard to display to make it show something. Nobody talks about it coz it's so simple like You need to plug in power cord to PC before turn on. If You have abosolutely no idea, start reading documentation for Your videocard, which usually called installation guide. There should be a sentence about connecting it to monitor and even some pictures.